# Анимация в Delphi

Tags: анимация, delphi

Требуется сделать светящиеся маяки. Анимационные Маяки сделаны в `gif`, но `Delphi` не поддерживает его, скачал я библиотеку `JEDI`, начал поддерживать, но отображается только первый кадр, я не знаю как сделать анимацию. Был вариант в `AVI` перевести, но то что вычитал из учебника, не сработало, сейчас пытаюсь понять в чём проблема.
Но вспомнил про замечательный `Flash`, и вроде библиотек хватает, но не знаю какую простую выбрать для отображения анимации `flv`, и как потом её установить и реализовать. Направьте, пожалуйста!

Comment: Flash Это ActiveX Элемент

Comment: Да, только я не могу в своей версии Lite найти как этот flash.ocx вставить.

Comment: В версии Lite
- Refactoring, ErrorInsite и поддержка ActiveX отключены, т.к. требуют наличия .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Не занимайтесь дурью, разбейте разложите gif в bmp и двигайте его.

разместите компонент image(где вам там надо) с размерами одного кадра, загрузите в него ленту (bmp). Добавляем таймер и пишем в него код:

```
with image do
begin
Left:=Left-Width div [количество кадров];
if Left=-Width then Left:=0;
end;
```

Comment: Боюсь моя программа будет весить больше чем сам Windows 7, ) так как там около 500 маяков анимированных. Этот вариант вообще никак не подходит.

Comment: там маяк наклоняется целиком что ли?))) И в любом случае мне казалось что можно подгружать графику динамически в Image.

Answer (score 1):

Могу выложить изящный код, отображающий "маяки" средствами OpenGL, но боюсь ваша програмка будет тогда предъявлять некие требования к аппаратной части пк. :) А так не надо маятся дурью, сохранить все покадрово в бмп или жпег и злибом пожать, склеить и динамически грузить. А ля пкг файлы кваки. )

Answer (score 0):

А если через TWebBrowser попробовать?

Comment: Ещё посмотрите вот этот компонент: http://www.tolderlund.eu/delphi/

Comment: Скачал TGIFImage
Там было 3 файла
gifimage.pas
gifimage.cnt
gifimage.txt
Я не могу понять как установить и как пользоваться?

Comment: Скорее всего в txt ответ

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что-то не так понял... Но компоненты библиотеки RxLib (например, RxLib_2.7.7.5 для Delphi c 6 по 2010) прекрасно справляются с вставкой анимированного GIF в формы. 
Обычно в скачанном архиве содержится инструкция по подключению, но если не окажется, то вот она:
1. Добавить в IDE путь к папке с библиотекой (..\RxLib\Units):
Tools->options 
 - Environment Options
   - Delphi Options
     - Library - Win32 | Library Path

- Открыть в IDE групповой проект:
  File->Open: ..\RxLib\packages\DelphiXXXX\Rxlib.groupproj
    (DelphiXXXX - Ваша версия Delphi)
- Ваполнить компиляцию вск пакетов проекта::
  Project-> Build All projects
- Инсталлировать пакеты:
  Una vez que todos los paquetes se han compilado correctamente se 
  deben instalar los que son de diseсo; Click derecho sobre los packages y
  pulsar [Install] (View -> Project Manager):

dclrx.bpl [install]
   dcldb.bpl [install]
   dcldb.bpl [install]